# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't fire when turning back to portrait

Tags: xcode, device-orientation

Here is the event:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    [self setupScrollView];
    return YES;
}
```

Any time the device is rotated, I setup my `UIScrollView` so that what's inside is always "right" side up.

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.scrollView.transform, M_PI);
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.scrollView.transform, -M_PI/2);
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.scrollView.transform, M_PI/2);
    }
```

This works except when the device is rotated from landscape back to Portrait (right side up), breakpoints verify that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not being called. So when device is turned back to portrait the `UIScrollView` contents are sideways. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why the above did not work, but the following seems to work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];  

//for some reason shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation isn't firing when returning to portrait so we need to register for notifications
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setupScrollView) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```